# Special price not showing in the submitted web order

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.8, php

Special prices are not getting pulled when a customer places an order on website.
We are on 1.8.1 community version

Special prices show on the checkout page of wishlists or individual shopping carts however when customer places an order, it pulls regular full price.

Any idea what could be an issue?

Answer (score 0):

Open your `phtml` file and Implement below logic where to show special price. Then get product price & compare like

```
$specialPrice = $_product->getFinalPrice();
$productPrice = $_product->getPrice();
if ($productPrice != $specialPrice)
{
   $productPrice = $specialPrice; // has special price
}
echo $productPrice;
```

Comment: Thanks Shorabh

I am not that technically sound, if you could help me out on locating the file, it would be great.

The special price is showing fine in the shopping cart and/or wishlist but once an order is placed, the regular full price gets pulled in to the order.

Comment: This code is only for wishlist . please open your "template/wishlist/item/column/price.phtml" file and update code like
 $item = $this->getItem();
$product = $item->getProduct();
$options = $this->getChild('customer.wishlist.item.options')
    ->setItem($item)
    ->getConfiguredOptions();
 
$specialPrice = $_product->getFinalPrice();
$productPrice = $_product->getPrice();
if ($productPrice != $specialPrice)
{
   $productPrice = $specialPrice; // has special price
}
echo $productPrice;   
?>
<div class="price">
     <?php echo number_format($productPrice,2);?> 
 </div>